# Percentile height doesn't work CSS. Fullscreen page possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a WebView in my android application and I have an interface that should (otherwise) be simple to design, but due to the issue with percentile based height not working I'm running into some issues.

The device should not have any scrolling and I need to lay the page out with certain elements containing a certain percentage size in the screen. Here's my CSS.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid green;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Now with the following HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">...</div>
</div>
```

I should have a container that takes up 60% of the screens height, correct? That would only make sense because the parent container takes up 100% of the screens height. This is absolutely essential to my applications completion and my goal was to be done by tomorrow and this is my last interface that requires being designed.

Thanks for any help.

NOTE:

I've also tried this:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `html, body` tags have `height: auto`, so it makes sense to style them first, just add full height for both

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
/*as this class is parent of #container, is also must have full height*/
.main-view{
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid green;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-view">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this and I'm not able to replicate. See: http://i.imgur.com/CiSqSL8.png

Comment: apply `height:100%` to all elements on top of `#container`, you definitely have more code behind, but basically, all parent elements must have full height to make this work. As example, i showed only for `html, body`, updated example

Comment: `html, body, ion-view, ion-content, #container`  That's all there is to it, unfortunately. Unless there's something inserted by JavaScript in the ionic framework I'm not aware of.

Comment: then apply `height: 100%` to `html, body, ion-view, ion-content`, note: there can be additional classes like `.scroll` and etc, apply to them also, why you even use you own header element? Ionic has built in support for headers

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll go and check through all of the classes I may be missing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using my own header element, just named it that way for the question. :P

Comment: The easiest way is to apply styles in browser dev tools and check result immediately

Comment: There it was, ".scroll" was the issue. I would have never found that without your guidance. It's not even in the HTML anywhere.

Comment: Comment for anyone else that has the problem, even tags like `<center>` require a 100% height setting.